# gfortran: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated

Tags: macos, bash, shell, fortran

I am starting to program in Fortran with gfortran recently on Mac OS X 10.6.8. I wrote the following simple `.f90` programs:

`sayhi.f90`:

```
subroutine sayhi()
  implicit none
  ! Display output to screen
  print*, 'Hello World'
end subroutine sayhi
```

and `main.f90`:

```
program main
  implicit none
  call sayhi()
end program
```

When I type the following command in Terminal, the program compiles as expected:

```
gfortran sayhi.f90 main.f90 -o helloworld.out
```

However, when I try to use a bash script `helloworld.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set your compiler (ifort, gfortran, or g95)
# Note: no space before equal sign
F90= gfortran

# Clear old files
rm *.o

# Compile and link (note: variable is used via a $ sign)
$F90 sayhi.f90 main.f90 -o helloworld.out
```

and type in Terminal

```
bash ./helloworld.sh
```

the following error returns:

```
gfortran: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
rm: *.o: No such file or directory
./helloworld.sh: line 11: sayhi.f90: command not found
```

I am sure that gfortran is properly installed, since directly inputing the command in Terminal works fine, and all the `.f90` and `.sh` files mentioned above are in the same directory, which is my present working directory. Even if I refrain from using the variable `F90` and use the `gfortran` command directly in the shell file, the same `no input files` problem occurs.

Could anyone help me identify what the problem is? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add spaces around the `=` symbol between when assigning variables.

```
F90= gfortran
```

should be

```
F90=gfortran
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
# Note: no space before equal sign
F90= gfortran
```

To

```
# Note: no space before OR AFTER the equal sign
F90=gfortran
```